# Store xml in both column store and row store in the same dbms

Tags: xml, row, columnstore

Hi I have a design question:

How can you design a system which hides XML database in both column store and row store in the same database management system efficiently?.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Comment: I mean for which type of queries of xml document , column store or row store will be more efficient. How would you design the system?. It is asked me to express it by one page in the exam.